# Removing the "Geometry Imports" and "Drawing" tools from the Map in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to remove the "Geometry Imports" and "Drawing" tools from the Map in Earth Engine. I have tried

```
Map.drawingTools().clear();
```

But it did not work. I was not able to find any solution from internet. Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build the Map yourself you can add whatever widgets you like after that.

```
ui.root.clear();

ui.root.add(ui.Map());
```

========================== Edit ==============

You can remove the drawingTools control on the default Map by setting the options of the map.

```
Map.setControlVisibility({
  drawingToolsControl:false
})
```

Comment: #Sean Roulet, thanks. I don't build the Map myself. I would like to remove the default Map.

Comment: See my change above